# Why or how does the WHERE IN statement works if the column name are different?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I want to create a **list of station** which only show the `usertype = 'Subscriber'`. So i build an inner query to extract `usertype` and `start_station_id` from `citibike_trips` table and match with the `name` and `station_id` from `citibike_stations` table. 2 different tables. I was wondering why or how does the `WHERE IN` statement works if both the column name(s) are different? `start_station_id != station_id`?

[image: This the concept that i understood since both the column name(s) are the same.]

[image: This the result if i only run the subquery.]

[image: This the result if i run the whole things.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your whole query is to get the values of `start_station_id` from `citibike_trips` table where `usertype` is equal to 'Subscriber', then use the pulled values to query in the `citibike_stations` table. As a result, any `start_station_id` pulled from your subquery that are not present in the `citibike_stations` table's `station_id` column will not be included in the output when you run your whole query.

If you only want to select rows with condition, `start_station_id != station_id`, you have to use the `NOT IN` syntax.

```
SELECT
    station_id, name
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.new-york_citibike.citibike_stations`
  WHERE station_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT start_station_id
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.new-york_citibike.citibike_trips`
        WHERE usertype = 'Subscriber');
```